# Query Multiple Keys for the Same Value in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query on multiple keys in my Firebase database

```
-users
  -De0pYw8liHRCZBBtoDibLoINbNA3
    -displayName: Bobby Davidson
    -email: bobDavidson@gmail.com
    -username: bobbyD1981
```

Given a single input (i.e., "bobby"), how can I setup my firebase query to match on both the `displayName` and `username` of the above user simultaneously?

I currently have the following which matches only on the username

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
ref.orderByChild('username').startAt(input).endAt(input + "\uf8ff").once("value")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. You may be able to combine the values that you want to filter on into a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase.